# Can a modern C/C++ compiler optimize better with the code in header?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, header-files

I've often heard that it is bad practice to place code in the header, but it's been common to place short functions in the headers, partly to help the compiler optimize better.

The inline keywords can help the compiler determine what functions should be inlined, but aside from that, is there still a reason to have short performance critical functions in the headers? Or does it not matter any more for modern compilers?

Comment: When you include a header file, the preprocessor literally copy and pastes the code in where you included it.

Comment: I suggest you take a look over here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180904/are-header-files-actually-good

Comment: `inline` mostly doesn't mean "make this code inline" in C++, it has more to do with how to resolve link time name collisions.  "Putting code inline" has little meaning in the context of the C++ standard.

Comment: Good compilers support "whole-program-optimization" which lets them inline functions between source files. Keep your header files short.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between marking a function inline, and writing it explicitly in declaration. Anyway, when it comes to c++,  those are just hints, and compilers are free to ignore them. They change semantics a little bit though, because you can link it from multiple translation units. Even if compiler does not chose to perform inlining you won't get a clash as if the function was actually inlined.

Comment: C ***XOR*** C++? No language called "C/C++" exists. You are asking about **either** C **or** C++ – and the answer depends very much on which language are you concerned with.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that even though inline is generally superfluous in C++ beyond indicating internal linkage, you generally don't want to be trying to inline anything yet, especially not with forceinline type specifiers. Reason: it can mess up your profiler sessions. Those inlined functions often don't show up as hotspots as opposed to the calling functions, so you start making it harder to tell where your bottlenecks are if you start going wild inlining everything based on conjectures rather than profiler results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, the `inline` keyword only means that the definition is allowed in multiple translation units. That is, if you have an inline function defined in a header file, and that header gets included in multiple source files, then that is fine.  For a non-inline, non-template function, that would be illegal.

But compilers can and do take advantage of being able to see the code of the function that is being called. This happens not only for inline functions but also any other functions whose code may be visible. Many compilers try to make a good guess about whether to inline the code. Having the code be inlined might make the program bigger or smaller, faster or slower.  If the compiler can determine that the code is likely to be both faster and smaller when the code is inlined, then it will do it. Otherwise it has to consider the trade-off.

Many modern compilers can do link-time optimization, where code that wasn't inlined to begin with can be inlined during the link phase, with some cost in link time. There may be certain optimization opportunities that are lost when delayed until link-time as well.

In my own experience, I've found that making small functions be inline is typically always a win for both size and speed. For larger functions, I often see it make the programs faster but larger, but I've also seen it rarely make the programs slower and larger. If the performance of a particular function is important, you'll need to do measurements to help make the choice of whether to inline or not.

Comment: Good info. The key piece here to me is "compilers can and do take advantage of being able to see the code of the function that is being called", and that this is true with link-time/whole-program optimization as well. I had hoped to deal with this only with readability in mind, but what you say makes sense, and as usual there seems to be no replacement for actual benchmarking. Thanks a bunch!